# Trying to understand this dynamic programming python code?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

So I am reading this excellent [intro](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-dynamic-programming-3efafb8d4296) to Dynamic Programming, and I am trying to decipher this python code (DP approach for Fibonacci numbers). I code mainly in C/C#, so its kinda hard for me to understand Python.
So this is the code:

```
def fibonacciVal(n):
    memo = [0] * (n+1)
    memo[0], memo[1] = 0, 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        memo[i] = memo[i-1] + memo[i-2]
    return memo[n]
```

So, the bits I am trying to understand are:

1. memo = [0] * (n+1) : I get that this is an array, but how are the values being stored here, how is it being initialized?
2. for i in range(2, n+1): : why is it looping till n+1, shouldn't it be till n only?

That's all. I am trying to decipher this myself, and it would help to have someone with python experience help me here.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a memoized version of fibonacci so it doesn't recompute already computed values.

Comment: The second arg in this use of  `range()` is when to stop.

Comment: Before you try to understand dynamic programming you need to understand the tools with which it's implemented.  Please look up the Python basics before posting here: initializing a list and the `range` iterator.

Comment: You could have figured all of this out in 10 minutes by reading the docs, 5 minutes by stepping through in a debugger, or 60 seconds by playing around with the repl. If you didn't know about any of those, well then ok, but now you know for next time.

Comment: The ```memo``` initialization can be shortened to ```memo = [0, 1] + [0] * (n-2)```

Comment: @Prune Yeah, I did that and I got it now, thanks.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, you were right. It took me a bit over 10 mins, but it was a rewarding experience. I used an online ide and some print statements. Thank you for reminding to not post these type of questions here. I will strictly refrain posting these simple questions from now on.

Comment: @accdias That's neat.

Comment: @benid seriously, don't forget about the repl. I rarely bother to look up the specifics of python syntax, I just alt-tab to a terminal and try out a couple of attempts followed by alt-tabbing back to my editor. If I were handed this code I'd e.g. multiply `[0]` by some numbers to see what it did, try to store values in the resulting list, etc.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `memo = [0] * (n+1)` : I get that this is an array, but how are the values being stored here, how is it being initialized?

When you multiply a one-element list by an integer in Python, it initializes a list with that one element repeated however many times you specified. For example, for `n=5`:

```
memo = [0] * (n+1)
```

will initialize a list of 6 `0`s and assign it to the variable `memo`.

```
>>> n = 5
>>> memo = [0] * (n+1)
>>> memo
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Be aware that this method for initializing lists works fine for lists of immutable objects (booleans, numbers, strings, etc.), but doesn't work very well for mutable objects (like lists of lists, or lists of dictionaries). This is because Python adds `n` copies of the *same object* to the list, which is not normally what you'd want. (When you try to change one of the mutable objects in your lists, all of them will change, since they're all just copies of the same object.)

---

> `for i in range(2, n+1)`: : why is it looping till n+1, shouldn't it be till n only?

It does stop at `n`, since that's the built-in behavior of the `range` function. When you pass in two arguments, they are its `start` and `stop` values. The `range` function will return the sequence from `start` (inclusive) to `stop` (exclusive).

If instead you said `range(2, n)`, it would stop at `n-1`. (Another way to think about it is, adding 1 to `n` is what makes it stop at `n`.)

Comment: Thank you ! This helped me understand Python a bit better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
1: [0]*3 -> [0,0,0] i.e. multiplying an array duplicates it that many times -n+1 in your case-.
2: because you start with [0,1,0,0,0, ...]
 the first index you add to is ^

... the last index you add to will be at n+1 because the first index you added to was 2
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,...]
```

Comment: I just explored the code mhyself, before reading the answers, and I did have it figured out. Reading your answer made my understanding more solidified. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What tools are you using for "trying to understand"?  A couple of basic `print` commands will help a lot:

```
def fibonacciVal(n):
    memo = [0] * (n+1)
    print("INIT", memo)
    memo[0], memo[1] = 0, 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        memo[i] = memo[i-1] + memo[i-2]
        print("TRACE", i, memo)
    return memo[n]

fibonacciVal(5)
```

Output:

```
INIT [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
TRACE 2 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
TRACE 3 [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]
TRACE 4 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0]
TRACE 5 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Yeah, print is the way to go when trying to understand something. Also, I was not aware of python having INIT and TRACE parameters for the print(). Thank you, you have enriched my knowledge!

Comment: Those are *not* parameters: they're merely text labels I use to differentiate the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
   dic ={}
    def febo (n):
    if n in dic:
        return dic[n]
    if n<=2:
        dic[n] = 1
    else:
        dic[n]  = febo(n-1) + febo(n-2)
    return dic[n]

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        n = int(input())
        print(febo(n))
```

##use this

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why this works?